# RMarkdown report with Plumber

Tags: r, r-markdown, plumber

I'm trying to create a pdf report from rmarkdown in plumber.
It works like this:

```
library(plumber)
#* @serializer contentType list(type="application/pdf")
#* @get /output/<runid>
function(runid){
  tmp <- tempfile()
  tmp <- rmarkdown::render("makePDF.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document",
                            params = list(runid = runid))
  readBin(tmp, "raw", n=file.info(tmp)$size)
}
```

But it creates a pdf file on my computer and I don't want this, because I consume this Plumber API with FastAPI like this:

```
router = APIRouter()
@router.get("/statistics/{id}", tags=['Statistics'])
def get_statistics(id):
    url = 'myurl' + id
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.content
    return Response(data, media_type='application/pdf')
```

Is it possible to send pdf to API and not creating it on the computer?